# Sigma 17-70mm f/2.8-4 OS HSM over Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II

Tags: lens, kit-lens

I own the Canon lens (on a 400D camera). Rather satisfied, but it is not an inspiring lens.

I refer most of all to image quality. I know Sigma has some more focal length and it is a good thing obviously. As for wider aperture I don't know if it has any value.

Is the Sigma worth it, considering that the Sigma costs (as of October 2012) about 300 euros more (which incidentally I could use to buy a GF2 with 14mm lens)? Is there a considerable improvement in image quality and general performance?

What other alternative for a standard zoom should I consider?

Comment: As always in these cases, you have to state better what your goals are. "Inspiring" is not precise enough: what kind of pictures are you trying to take and not capturing because of the limited "inspiration" provided by the lens?

Answer (score 2):

A wider lens (f/2.8 @ 17 mm vs f/3.5 at 18mm, f/4 vs f/5.6 at the tele end) can give you possibilities which you wouldn't have otherwise, in terms of depth of field and/or of bokeh (greater presence of roundly-shaped out-of-focus highlights). This can help your inspiration but it depends on the kind of shots that you are aiming for. Besides, you will be able to use the lens in situation with reduced light (like indoor). This applies more to the wide end of the lens (17mm) where distortion will be more pronounced: so keep it in mind if you plan to use this lens for indoor portraits without flash or other lightning gear.

The greater focal length, in the same way, can be used for tighter framing, which can be useful e.g. for portraits or, as this [blog post](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/thinking-outside-the-box-telephoto-landscapes/) shows, for a different take on landscape (but 70mm is probably a bit too short for that, in my experience).

So the Sigma lens obviously surely offers some capabilities that your current kit lens doesn't have or offer in the same amount. If it is worth a given amount of euros depends on your commitment to the hobby and to your satisfaction with the pics that you are able to take (or dissatisfaction with those that you are unable to).